# Como criar uma Managed Thread em C++ semelhante ao exemplo em C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, thread

Em **C#** eu utilizo o seguinte código para criar a Managed Thread:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(minhaFuncao));
```

Em **C++** eu fiz:

```
using namespace System::Threading;
    .
    .
    Thread^ thread = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(this,PutToSleep));
```

e ao dar rebuild, muitos erros acabam sendo acusados, somente com esses trechos do código.

Como fazer uma managed thread em C++ que funcione como a linha de código acima do C#?

Comment: Acredito que valha a pena editar a pergunta, para deixar claro que se trata da criação de Managed Threads em C++, usando CLR

Comment: Concordo. Seria bom também incluir os erros acusados pelo compilador na pergunta. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro está na linha

> Thread^ thread = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(this,PutToSleep));

Para se criar a managed thread deve ser passado o ponteiro do método (está faltando o operador &), e o nome do método deve estar completamente qualificado:

```
Thread^ thread = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(&NOME_DA_CLASSE::NOME_DO_METODO));
```

Conforme mostra o exemplo aqui no MSDN: [Thread Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-2)

Comment: Valeu Rafa, e pq gcnew?? não só new ?? gcnew é pra referenciar ?

Comment: Tem que usar o gcnew sempre que for criar um objeto que vai para o Managed heap (onde o garbage collector pode agir). Se utilizar só new o objeto vai para o heap normal do sistema, e o garbage collector não tem como monitorar

Comment: justamente porque é uma thread que a execução vai acabar em algum ponto? assim ao acabar a thread ele já joga no Managed heap pro garbage collector fazer oque é preciso ??

Comment: Na verdade não só porque é uma thread, mas porque é um objeto marcado para tanto, na declaração da classe. Essa classe Thread é declarada assim **public ref class Thread**, indicando ao compilador que ela deve ser criada com o gcnew, para ser controlada pelo garbage collector. Se a declaração fosse **public class Thread**, aí seria o contrário: você só poderia dar new, e não gcnew, por ser uma classe comum.